# HttpPost fails doing its function

Tags: android, http, post, try-catch, progressdialog

I'm trying to send a URL with some parameters using HttpPost but it has no success. I'm using this code:

```
public void Exchange()
{
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang").getString("doTheAction"), true, false);
        new Thread(){
                public void run() {

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try {
                        httpclient.execute(new HttpPost(URL));
                        Merchant.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                                public void run(){
                                    Again();
                                } 
                           });

                    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                    finally { httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); }
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
        }.start();
}
```

It doesn't do anything but it has to change some values on a MySQL database. Can someone help me? It seems that is all correct.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An Http-POST without POST values looks somewhat useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to post data to server via API, then changing some values on a MySQL database is server-side tasks

```
    public static String post(String to, List <NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(to);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePost = client.execute(post);  
            HttpEntity resEntityPost = responsePost.getEntity();  
            if (resEntityPost != null) return EntityUtils.toString(resEntityPost);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("POST", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want  to check `HttpResponse` returned by `httpClient.execute()`. You may want to check `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` maybe it's not 200. You may also want to check your server logs does it receive anything? Also are you sure `IOException` is not thrown?